# How to find the smallest N

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that determines the survivor from a list of names to walk the plank in this scenario, the last person in the list survives
the code i have for this is:

```
names =  ["Andrew", "Brenda", "Craig", "Deidre", "Edward", "Felicity", "Greg", "Harriet"]
def survivor(names, step):
    Next = step - 1
    while len(names) > 1:
        names.pop(Next)
        Next = Next + step
        Next = (Next - 1) % len(names)
        print names

    return names[0]
```

this works to return the survivor based on what put in step but i also need to work out the smallest N for step for a person to survive e.g. 3 for greg and 2 for andrew.

the codes i have tried for this are:

```
assert name in names
for step in survivor(names, step):
    if survivor == name:
        return step
```

but  it keeps saying local variable step referenced before assignment or global step is not defined.

and

```
assert name in names
for step in itertools.count(1):
    if survivor(names, step) == name:
        return step
```

but this returns

['Brenda', 'Craig', 'Deidre', 'Edward', 'Felicity', 'Greg', 'Harriet']

['Craig', 'Deidre', 'Edward', 'Felicity', 'Greg', 'Harriet']

['Deidre', 'Edward', 'Felicity', 'Greg', 'Harriet']

['Edward', 'Felicity', 'Greg', 'Harriet']

['Felicity', 'Greg', 'Harriet']

['Greg', 'Harriet']

['Harriet']

which is not what i want

Can anyone help me work this out?

Comment: What exactly is this loop supposed to do?

Comment: @jadkik94 AFAICT, `return names[-1]`

Comment: This question is about the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Answer (score 2):

This loop does not do what you expect. What you want should be similar to this:

```
def shortest(name):
    assert name in names
    for step in range(1, len(names)+1):
        #Go through all possible steps, from 1 to number of items (the +1 is to include the last item too)
        if survivor(names[:], step) == name: # Check that this item matches
            return step # Break out of the loop when you get to it
```

The `itertools.count(1)` would work, but you could just as well use a `while True` and it makes no sense to have a step greater than the length of the names list.

Your problem was probably with the names array becoming empty after the first name. Because you are `pop`ing out all the elements, and modifying the `names` list which is in the global scope (defined out of the function). So you have to duplicate it (using either `names[:]` or `list(names)` which will both achieve the same purpose).

That's the test I made:

```
for n in names:
    print n, shortest(n)
```

And the output:

```
Andrew 2
Brenda None
Craig 5
Deidre 7
Edward None
Felicity 4
Greg 3
Harriet 1
```

**Note:** I don't know why there are `None`s in there... but the examples you gave did match!

Comment: Thank you @jadkik94 i really appreciate it, been trying for ages

Answer (score 1):

```
for step in survivor(names, step):
```

Notice how you're using `step` twice here. How is Python supposed to pass it to the `survivor` function before it gets it out of that function?

I *think* what you want is the [`range` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). This will loop through every `step` value from 1 to the length of the list of names:

```
for step in range(1, len(names)):
```

Your `itertools.count` version should also work, now that I think about it. Are you checking the return value of this function or just looking at what it prints out? The output looks like it's from this line:

```
print names
```

One other thing is that your function changes the original list every time it runs, since you change `names` and you're not making a copy. Maybe you want to make a copy before changing it:

```
def survivor(names, step):
    names = names[:]
    # etc
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for why `names[:]` creates a copy of the list.

Comment: i have been trying it every way i can think of, i just cant get it working, im not sure how

Comment: @user1839493 I updated the answer with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: it returns an integer which is what i need it to do but it doesnt return the right number
i have been working with step = 3 which means greg survives but when i use your suggested piece of code it returns 1 when it should be 3

Comment: @user1839493 I think it's doing that because you alter the original list every time you call this function. See my last edit.

Comment: even with the edit it does the same thing, playing around with it it seems the number entered in the brackets for the range function is what gets returned

Comment: @user1839493 Sorry I had a typo, should be `names = names[:]` to make the copy.